# Cannot read property 'text' of undefined - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Todat I am stuck with looping in Vue. I know the basics of loops and been looking around if these question are asked before. But none of them solved my problem.

Code loop:

```
<ul>
    <li :v-for="todo in todos">
       {{ todo.text }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Code object:

```
todos: [
   { text: "Subscibe to Renatello.com newsletter", done: true },
   { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
   { text: "Build awesome projects", done: false }
]
```

The error I get is: **Cannot read property 'text' of undefined**

Hopefully there is someone out here which can help me out.

**SOLUTION:**

The :v-for: as v-for="(todo, index) in todos" with an :key="index"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code object is wrong. Check the curly braces

Comment: Yea I see it now... but I had inserted those curly braces

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) and specifically, [here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406293/157247) how to do one for Vue.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the colon before the v-for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not strong on Vue, but I don't think you want the `:` on `:v-for`, just `v-for`:

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        todos: [
            {
                text: "Subscibe to Renatello.com newsletter",
                done: true
            },
            {
                text: "Learn Vue",
                done: false
            },
            {
                text: "Build awesome projects",
                done: false
            }
        ]
    }
})

setTimeout(() => {
    app.todos = [
        ...app.todos,
        {
            text: "more",
            done: false
        }
    ];
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="todo in todos">
            {{ todo.text }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```